# Ending a letter in Latin

Tags: idiom

Salvete,

How would I sign my name at the end of a letter in Latin?  Would the Nominative (Paulus) case be the normal way? Or do I need the ablative (Paulō) to imply "from/by Paulus"?

Gratias vobis ago.

Paulus/Paulō  ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The final chapter of Milena Minkova's introductory textbook on composition is about letter writing. The classical examples she gives put the name of the sender in the nominative *at the beginning*, not at the end, with the addressee in the dative, typically a with term of endearment.

> *Tullius Terentiae suae* (Tully to his Terentia)

These letters typically end with *vale* or *valete* or any one of many alternatives. In the Vulgate, Saint Paul ends his with a blessing. He mentions his name, however, at the end of 1 Corinthians, at the end of Colossians, and at the end of 2 Thessalonians, *Salutatio mea manu Pauli* (in the hand of Paul).

Vatican *decreta*, for what it's worth, are typically signed at the bottom, like our modern day letters, preceded by the location and date of the signature. An example from my prayer book:

> Ex aedibus Congregationis pro Cultu Divino, die 7 aprilis 1985, dominica Paschae, in Resurectione Domini.
>
> Augustinus Mayer, Pro-Praefectus
>
> Vergilius Noe, a Secretis

Which means, I think, that Augustinus authorized the *decretum*, which Vergilius wrote.

Prefaces to books are also written in a similar style, but I can't seem to find an example easily. It's not obvious that Kurt Aland, Barbara Aland, Michael Hetzenauer, or Roger Gryson, who wrote prefaces that I have on my shelf, are putting their names in the nominative or simply not declining them.

Comment: Excellent answer thank you!