# Translation for "Humbly yours in Christ"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am trying to find the correct translation for, "humbly yours in Christ" to put at the end of a letter. Would the translation "humilitate tua in Christo" be somewhat close? I have just recently begun studying Latin. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though *humilitas / humilis* was mostly negative in classical Latin, it acquired its positive sense as a Christian virtue as early as the Vulgate (Matthew 11:29; James 4:6), Augustine (*Confessions* I.11) and certainly by the time of Aquinas ([*Summa Theologiae* II-II, q. 161](https://www.corpusthomisticum.org/sth3155.html)). This has a lot to do with the Christian emphasis on what Alasdair MacIntyre calls the "virtues of acknowledged dependence": whereas Aristotle only had the vice of pusillanimity, Aquinas acknowledges not only the vice but also the virtue of humility.

Another prefatory remark: the classical way of composing Latin letters (followed by authors as diverse as Cicero, Seneca, Petrarch, and Erasmus) is to name the sender and recipient *at the beginning* (e.g. "Seneca Lucilio suo salutem") and then to have a valediction at the end, often with the time and place. For more on this, see this question: [Ending a letter in Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13779/ending-a-letter-in-latin). Nevertheless, there is also precedent for ending Latin letters in the way we are accustomed to.

A literal translation of your phrase is: **humiliter tuus in Christo**. I can't find any precedent for this, though, and I'm not sure if Latin shares this formula with English: it's strange for an adverb to modify a possessive pronoun.

I would suggest adding a noun, e.g. "servus" (=servant), for which I have found some precedent. You could thus close your letter with: **humilis servus tuus in Christo [name]**. This literally means, "Your humble servant in Christ." You could also substitute *humillimus* (="most humble").

Comment: It is not strange to adverb to preceding a pronoun: it's just American English way. And this situation is rule for many other languages in such type of the letter-end cliché.

Comment: Hmm, can you give me some examples? From my (limited) knowledge of letter-writing in other European languages, I can't think of an example of "adverb + yours." Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding your comment: if your point is that it's only common in English, then that's what I was intending to say!

Comment: @Josh: (Oxford); servus, i (m) = a slave; as an adjective: servus-a-um--having the status of a slave, servile. Is this what you want?

Comment: @tony Again, "servus" has a vastly different meaning in a Christian context. See, for instance, Romans 1:1, or the Pope's title: "servus servorum Dei"

Comment: @brianpck Ok. Look at here: British English - yours sincerely (pronoun+adverb), but American English (mostly) - sincerely yours (adverb+pronoun); Russian - iskrenne vash (adverb+pronoun); French - as cliché: bien à vous (dual treatment by me: or ajective+preposition 'to'+pronoun, so literally 'good for you', or adverb+(preposition-pronoun compound),  so literally 'pleasantly yours'), as speech example: sincèrement à vous/vôtre - 'sincerely yours' (adverb+(preposition-pronoun compound)/adverb+pronoun).

Comment: But it seems to be more useful for you. There was example similar to question theme: 'sincèrement vôtre en Jésus-Christ' in Trench. So you can use calque from French expression: 'sincērē vostrī(masc.)/vostrae(fem.) in Jesus Christus'.

Comment: It was answer to the topic-starter (@Josh)

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't even think of rephrasing it as being, "your servant in Christ". Now I'll place more attention on the semantics during translation.

Answer (score 3):

The expression; "humilitate tua in Christo" means "with your humility in Christ", not quite what you have requested. A second problem is that "humilitas" is harsher, in Latin, than "humility" in English e.g. lowness; meanness; insignificance (Oxford).

A possible alternative: "minister tibi in Christo" = "a servant to you in Christ".

Here, "minister" is not so obsequious or humiliating as "humilitas"; besides "servant", "minister" = attendant; accomplice; agent.

Lewis & Short give more examples e.g. promoter; helper; an abettor; accomplice.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why "tibi" instead of "tuus"?

Comment: @brianpck Since the verb *servire* is used with a dative, it makes sense to me to use the same case for the beneficiary of the corresponding noun. Perhaps I'm mislead by other languages, but I'd read a genitive or a possessive pronoun as ownership and a dative more as a favour. Tony, could you elaborate on this choice in your answer?

Comment: @brianpck & Joonas: The use of "tibi" seemed to be more personal (a servant to you) without being obsequious. I was unsure about the grammatical acceptability of this, and was anticipating a challenge. As for "servus" the thinking was that, in Rome, the servants and the slaves might have been one-and-the-same species, hence the Oxford definition. As you have indicated, "servus" would have evolved, with time. I liked the work you did (2016) in finding examples (Vulgate)  of sentences which included pairs of perfect subjunctives. Great!

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Please see comment to brianpck, above.

Comment: @brianpck: I forgot to reference the Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1179/1982 which included the Vulgate examples.

Answer (score 1):

There was a greeting to a noble men in the former Austria-Hungary Empire: sounded like 'servus humillimus' (now clipped just to a 'servus' in some languages, which natives were citizens of the empire). Maybe it's possible to re-phrase expression in such way. Not adverb, but compound to modify pronoun. It sounds less pejoratively.

Answer (score 1):

@Josh When I was answering to @brianpck, there was example from French. And I did give advice to use calque from this language - 'sincērē vostrī in JC'. But there is an another possible variant: 'sincērē vestrum (in JS)'.