# What are the meanings of servus and minister in ecclesiatical latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-comparison, ecclesiastical-latin

Reading the answers to [another question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14095/translation-for-humbly-yours-in-christ) I thought about the meaning of *servus* and *minister* in christian/ecclesiastical latin.

It seems to me that in classical latin *servus* related clearly to the legal status of the person while *minister* had a broader sense.

In the Church we know the title *Servus servorum dei* using *servus* as well for the people of God as for the Pope. Both are no slaves in a technical sense. The [Code of Canon Law](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_INDEX.HTM) uses *minister* in particular for people with functions in the Church, esp. for the *ministri sacri seu clerici* (e.g. *"Liber II Pars I Titulus II De ministris sacris seu de clericis"*). So the word is used in a narrower sense.

How are the words *servus* and *minister* characterized in eccleasiatical latin? What are the nuances of the meanings?